# How to teach new parents to apply early childhood education to improve cognitive outcomes in their children?

Tags: pre-schooler, education, homeschooling

**What are the most common ways for new parents to put in practice early childhood education?**

I'm asking because it seems there is enough information available that one would expect to find trainers, facilitators or even groups of people applying or teaching programs of preschool education, by both either public or private institutions.

**What follows is all the findings that makes me think that's the case:**

I watched the documentary ["My Brilliant Brain: Born Genius"](http://natgeotv.com/asia/my-brilliant-brain/about) where they refer to the [Abecedarian Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abecedarian_Early_Intervention_Project), in that investigation, a group of children that were exposed to early childhood education observed long-term benefits, such as higher scores in intelligence tests than those children that weren't exposed to the program.

Due to the importance in the findings on the Abecedarian Project, I also [asked](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/2082/2516) for any peer-reviewed or follow-up studies on the subject, but the only studies I could find were those listed on the [project's page](http://abc.fpg.unc.edu/scholarly-publications).

Also searching for related information it seems that there are multiple programs available by the name of [The Abecedarian Approach](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Abecedarian+Approach%22) that offer similar results. Among them, I am aware of at least [one of them](http://www.socio.com/eipardd01.php) that has some of the [investigators](http://abc.fpg.unc.edu/investigators) in the original project ([Craig T. Ramey](http://research.vtc.vt.edu/people/craig-ramey/) and [Joseph J. Sparling](http://fpg.unc.edu/node/3957)).

There is also a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvQQMY6TyUdt5VeHpuHv_Dg) by the [New America foundation](https://www.newamerica.org) with some videos on the subject. Like for instance [Too Much Evidence to Ignore: New Findings on the Impact of Quality Preschool at Scale](https://youtu.be/4H315bSb3xk)

Also looking for related books, it seems all the investigators in the original project have published some literature on the subject:

[Craig T. Ramey](https://www.amazon.com/Craig-T.-Ramey/e/B001K8U916/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1498326276&sr=1-1), 
[Joseph Sparling](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_2?ie=UTF8&text=Joseph+Sparling&search-alias=books&field-author=Joseph+Sparling&sort=relevancerank), 
[Isabelle Lewis](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Isabelle+Lewis&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3AIsabelle+Lewis), 
[Margaret R. Burchinal](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Margaret+R.+Burchinal&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3AMargaret+R.+Burchinal), 
[Elizabeth Pungello](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Elizabeth+Pungello&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3AElizabeth+Pungello), 
[Lynne Vernon-Feagans](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Lynne+Vernon-Feagans&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3ALynne+Vernon-Feagans), and 
[Barbara Hanna Wasik](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Barbara+Hanna+Wasik&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3ABarbara+Hanna+Wasik).

Based on all that information, it seems there is enough material available for specialized training on early childhood education, that's why I'm asking in the first place.

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand.  I am not even sure if you are asking for a single source to find all the information a new parent is seeking or if you are asking for a platform for which to share info with new parents seeking info.

Comment: @threetimes I added an explanation at the end although I'll rethink the question to make it more clear. Also, I don't like to remove all the "evidence" and links to support it just because I want to have them at hand for personal use.

Comment: @threetimes I've edited the question, I hope is more clear now, thanks for point out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Carolina Abecedarian Project had a curriculum comprised of [four key elements](http://abc.fpg.unc.edu/design-and-innovative-curriculum):

Language Priority, Conversational Reading, Enriched Caregiving, and [LearningGames®](http://fpg.unc.edu/resources/learninggames-abecedarian-curriculum-birth-12-months).

In the UK there is the [Early Years Foundation Stage](https://www.gov.uk/early-years-foundation-stage) (EYFS) that has a similar curriculum that covers from birth to 5 years.

In Australia professor Sparling is Director of the [3A (Abecedarian Approach Australia) Project](https://3a.education.unimelb.edu.au/about-the-abecedarian-approach) that offers courses and certifications. There is also [free resources and free Abecedarian play groups](http://logantogether.org.au/abecedarian-approach-for-all/) delivered by [Kingston East Neighbourhood Centre](http://www.keng.org.au) in Logan City.

Those seem to me the more accessible places were to find information on the subject from the English speaking countries. If I find something else I'll update the answer.

**Edit:**
In the US professor Sparling also offers a [training course](http://pdc.fpg.unc.edu/abecedarian-approach-providing-evidence-based-care-and-education-early-childhood-settings-levels-i-a), so I guess one could get in touch with them to get information on when and where those trainees are going to offers their services.